After adding nginx as reverse proxy for caching api response, my login post request is failing
This is my nginx.conf file i made a folder nginx on my linux server where i am running my dockerised container apps.

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=1g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

    server {
        listen 8082;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://ejaz-api:80;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_cache my_cache;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        }

        # Define cache settings for API requests
        location /api/meejaz/v1/Account/login {
            proxy_pass http://ejaz-api:80;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
            proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;

            proxy_cache off; 
        }

        # Handle HTTP/2 and WebSocket connections
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://meejaz-api:80;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

And inside my docker-compose.yaml i defined nginx as below:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: my-nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/cache:/var/cache/nginx
    user: root
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    networks:
      - applab-meejaz-nw

How can i interecept response, or how can i know the response is actually cached at nginx and i am getting response from nginx. Any helpful advice is appreciated
